# Adding a prefix to a list of file names in a hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

The array `@lines` contains the keys of `%hash` like this

```
HG00117
HG00119
NA20828
```

And so on for other many samples. I just showed three for the example below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

open (FILE, 'input.txt'); 
chomp (my @lines = (<FILE>)); 
close(FILE);

my %hash;

$hash{$_} = [ glob("$_*.bam") ] for @lines;

dd %hash;
```

This will print me my hash of arrays:

```
(
  "HG00117",
  [
    "HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
    "HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "HG00117.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
  ],
  "HG00119",
  [
    "HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
    "HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "HG00119.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
  ],
  "NA20828",
  [
    "NA20828.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.exome.20121211.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "NA20828.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
    "NA20828.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.low_coverage.20130415.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "NA20828.mapped.illumina.mosaik.TSI.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
  ],
)
```

I want to prefix each element of the arrays with `INPUT=`, so they look like this

```
(
  "HG00117",
  [
    "INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
    "INPUT=HG00117.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "INPUT=HG00117.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
  ],
  "HG00119",
  [
    "INPUT=HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.exome.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "INPUT=HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
    "INPUT=HG00119.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.GBR.low_coverage.20120522.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "INPUT=HG00119.mapped.illumina.mosaik.GBR.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
  ],
  "NA20828",
  [
    "INPUT=NA20828.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.exome.20121211.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "INPUT=NA20828.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.low_coverage.20101123.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
    "INPUT=NA20828.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.TSI.low_coverage.20130415.bam_herc2_data.bam",
    "INPUT=NA20828.mapped.illumina.mosaik.TSI.exome.20110411.bam_herc2_phase1.bam",
  ],
)
```

I tried regex and `grep` but nothing seems to work. I think I'm getting confused with the scope of `foreach`. I also tried the `rename` function but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you need the hash structure apart from for the renaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, iterating every element - you actually need two loops. One for the 'top level' - the hash values. (Which are array references).

Then with each array reference, iterate within those applying a transform.

```
foreach my $array_ref ( values %hash ) {
   foreach my $oldfilename ( @$array_ref ) {
       $element =~ s/^/INPUT=/;
   }
}
```

Or did you actually want to change the filenames *on disk*? If so, you can use [`rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) (I don't think this is what you want though)

```
foreach my $array_ref ( values %hash ) {
   foreach my $oldfilename ( @$array_ref ) {
       rename $oldfilename, 'INPUT='.$oldfilename
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use `values` instead of `keys` as you don't need the keys for the operation.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'm feeling dumb for not knowing stuff like this...but I know that as a new guy in programming I'll learn with time and practice!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: No.. I don't need to change in the disk! I need to put the INPUT= at the beginning because they will be part of source command where I need to put the `*.bam` file as `INPUT=*.bam` and so on.

Comment: Ok. then ignore the second bit. You mentioned `rename` which would have changed the filenames in that way :)

Comment: Oh...I see! So rename will actually change the files on disk. Yeah..this could lead me to big mess! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done neatly by building a regular expressions out of the contents of `input.txt`, and checking all `*.bam` files against it.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @patterns = do {
  open my $in_fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die qq{Unable to open "input.txt" for input: $!};
  <$in_fh>;
};
chomp @patterns;
my $re = join '|', map quotemeta, @patterns;

my @files = grep /^(?:$re)/, glob '*.bam';
$_ = "INPUT=$_" for @files;
```

Comment: I see... so here it will be applicable outside the %hash? I don't even need the %hash in the first place?

Comment: Okay I've chnaged my answer as I thought *"rename the files"* meant renaming the files!

Comment: Yes, correct. The array `@files` contains the modified names of all the files that start with any of the strings in `input.txt` and end with `.bam`. That's why I asked if you needed the hash, as a simple list of files is much easier.